# Android own Activity start function

Tags: android, android-activity

i've tried to start an activity with my own function, but it doesn't work (think its a logic fault ;) )

Please have a look at:

```
Intent adder = new Add().execute(this, Add.class, "Test:","Add the test");
        startActivity(adder);
```

This is the Activity which i want to start:

```
 public class Add extends Activity {

public Intent execute(Context context, Class<?> cls, String addText, String buttonText) {
    TextView addStr = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.addtext);
    addStr.setText(addText);
    Button addBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addbtn);
    addBtn.setText(buttonText);
    return new Intent(context, cls);
}
```

}

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [this Android developer guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html), which talks about Activity and Intent.  I think you will see that they are used in a completely different way than you are trying to use them.

Comment: How do you think what i see in an activity? I wanted to use one activity for two actions, so i have to change some texts in the activity.